# How to hide the NavigationBar when i use SWRevealViewController embed in UINavigationController?

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, xcode5

When i use SWRevealViewController as initial view or not embedded in UINavigationController the result is as i expected:

[image]

but when the SWRevealViewController comes from UINavigationController tee result is:
[image]

How can i avoid the NavigationBar presented in the Rear view?

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following code to the viewWillAppear: method of the viewcontroller whose navigation bar you need to hide.

```
  [super viewWillAppear:YES];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, this code for rear view controller

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue & It did not work for me .. Is there any other suggestions ? ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need Navigation Controller on top of SWRevealViewController:

You got to hide navigation bar from navigation controller of your SWRevealViewController.
U can do this in IB (assuming you are using Storyboards):

1. Select Navigation Controller in your Storyboard
2. Open Attributes inspector
3. Find section "Navigation Controller", uncheck "Shows Navigation Bar"

[image: Where to set navigation bar to hidden]

Next, If you want navigation bard in front view controller, then attach it to separate Navigation Controller. You will have two Navigation Controllers, think on which one you want to push - it will have different effect.